# When is the Cartesian product of two sets open and connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Two non-empty subsets $\mathsf{X}, \mathsf{Y}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Which conditions on $\mathsf{X}$ and $\mathsf{Y}$ are necessary and sufficient for
$$
\mathsf{Z} = \mathsf{X}\times\mathsf{Y}
$$
to be an open and connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$?

Comment: According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653106/is-the-cartesian-product-of-two-open-sets-open) question, the product of two **open** sets is an **open** set. 

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338027/product-of-connected-spaces) question, the product of two **connected** sets is a **connected** set. 
Therefore if $\mathsf{X}$ and $\mathsf{Y}$ are open and connected, then so is $\mathsf{Z}$. These are sufficient conditions. What are necessary conditions though?

Comment: I think that the projections onto the two components from $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ are open mappings. Moreover they are continuous. Thus they map connected sets to connected ones.